# Construct an arrangement of numbers that the absolute value of differences between adjacent numbers are all different

Tags: permutations, contest-math

In the original duscussion: [Different Differences between an Arrangement of Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3156408/different-differences-between-an-arrangement-of-numbers), the problem has the limitation: 3 is in the third place, and it provide the answer choices from $12$ to $16$. I want to know if there is a way to construct all possible arrangement without the limitation, or at least calculate how many ways there are?

My attempt:
I consider arranging $1,2,3,4,5$ to let the sum of any consecutive numbers is not $0$ mod $6$, and I got $(4,1,3,5,2)$ and $(1,4,3,2,5)$ (reverse is eligible too). Let starting number from $1$ to $6$, and add the adding sequence to see if it works.

For ex: use the sequence $(4,1,3,5,2)$ and mod $6$
$1$ $5$ $6$ $3$ $2$ $4$ $-$ X 
$2$ $6$ $1$ $4$ $3$ $5$ $-$ O 
$3$ $1$ $2$ $5$ $4$ $6$ $-$ X 
starting from $4$,$5$,$6$ is the reverse of upper sequence.

use the sequence $(1,4,3,2,5)$ and mod $6$
$1$ $2$ $6$ $3$ $5$ $4$ $-$ X 
$2$ $3$ $1$ $4$ $6$ $5$ $-$ X 
$3$ $4$ $2$ $5$ $1$ $6$ $-$ O 
starting from $4$,$5$,$6$ is the reverse of upper sequence.

Other sequences from $(2,5,3,1,4)$ and $(5,2,3,4,1)$ are:
$2$ $4$ $3$ $6$ $1$ $5$ 
$1$ $6$ $2$ $5$ $3$ $4$

However, there are many other sequences that don't meet the condition I set. For ex: 
$4$ $2$ $3$ $6$ $1$ $5$
is the sequence from $4$ and the difference mod $6$ $(4,1,3,1,4)$, because the first $4$ is actually $-2$ and the second $1$ is actually $-5$.

I am a little bit confused about the process of construction. Are there appropriate thinking process to deal with this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why don't you continue from the steps in the solution? EG You know that $1-6$ must happen, and we have either $5-1-6$ or $1-6-2$ (which are the "same sequence", where we take 7 minus each term, so can proceed WLOG). How can we get a difference of 3? We need $1-4, 2-5, 3-6$, so continue from there.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try it.